# Failing to get window_handles with selenium chromedriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Recently, after updating chrome to 55+, I started getting errors while trying to get window handles via [GET /session/:sessionId/window_handles](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#sessionsessionidwindow_handles):

> unknown error: DevTools returned unknown type:shared_worker

Here's a piece of raw response:

```
{
      "state": "unhandled error",
      "sessionId": "eb9c00d1-69b5-442f-a7ec-22ec3f66ebe8",
      "hCode": 2083613825,
      "value": {
        "additionalInformation": "\nDriver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver\nCapabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.26.436421 (6c1a3ab469ad86fd49c8d97ede4a6b96a49ca5f6), userDataDir=/var/folders/2b/9hrnxzzn01g5h6f63y0xr6x00000gp/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.6K7w6K}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=55.0.2883.95, platform=MAC, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]\nSession ID: 059342d1acb4b69e7b7ba68a3b1073ea",
        "localizedMessage": "unknown error: DevTools returned unknown type:shared_worker\n  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.95)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436421 (6c1a3ab469ad86fd49c8d97ede4a6b96a49ca5f6),platform=Mac OS X 10.9.5 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)\nCommand duration or timeout: 3 milliseconds\nBuild info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'\nSystem info: host: 'MBP', ip: '10.10.10.01', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.5', java.version: '1.8.0_25'\nDriver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver\nCapabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.26.436421 (6c1a3ab469ad86fd49c8d97ede4a6b96a49ca5f6), userDataDir=/var/folders/2b/9hrnxzzn01g5h6f63y0xr6x00000gp/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.6K7w6K}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=55.0.2883.95, platform=MAC, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]\nSession ID: 059342d1acb4b69e7b7ba68a3b1073ea",
...
}
```

It fails with both single and multiple tabs. Also, `/session/:sessionId/window_handle` seems to work fine.

chromedriver: 2.26.436421

selenium: 2.53.1

chrome: 55.0.2883.95

Anyone has an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in ChromeDriver that was fixed in v2.27:

> ----------ChromeDriver v2.27 (2016-12-23)----------
>
> Supports Chrome v54-56
>
> Resolved issue 1637: Getting window handles fails in the presence of shared workers on Chrome 55+ [['OS-All', 'Pri-1']]